# What is the right way to use :value and v-model together in a <input>

Tags: vue.js

this is my wrong code:

```
<input v-model="input.nameInput" type="text" :value="name" autocomplete="off" class="form-control">
<input v-model="input.posInput" type="text" :value="pos" autocomplete="off" class="form-control">
```

i can display the {{name}} and the {{pos}} outer of  and its work. but if v-model and :value merged, error:

v-bind:value="name" conflicts with v-model on the same element because the latter already expands to a value binding internally

so what is the correct way? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

value is the same as v-model, v-model however updates on input where value does not.

There have been a few times I've used value over v-model but if you do this you would have to watch on input and change and update the value using a function instead.

do the following for this.

```
<input v-model="input.nameInput" type="text" autocomplete="off" class="form-control">
<input v-model="input.posInput" type="text" autocomplete="off" class="form-control">
```

Remove the value and keep the v-model.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use both v-bind and v-model on the same element. Consider the following code:

```
<label>
  Input with v-bind 
  <input v-bind:value="message" />
</label>
<label>
  Input with v-model
  <input v-model="message" />
</label>
<p>{{ message }}</p>
```

The input with `v-bind:value="message"` (or it's shorthand, `:value="message"` will do the exact same), implements one-way binding. Any changes done to the "message" variable will be updated in this input, but changes done in the v-bind input will not change the message variable.

The input with `v-model="message"` has two-way binding. This means that changes to the input will reflect the message variable, but changes to the message variable will also reflect on the input. If you're building a form in vue, this type of binding is usually the way to go.

I made a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Robb216/1dxwuk58/) where you can test both types of binding.

If your intention with both a v-bind and a v-model was to set a default value to your input field, you can set this value in the component's data.

```
data: {
  message: 'My default value',
}
```

Or, if your fields are managed by a parent component (via props), you can set the initial value with `default: "My default value"`.

```
props: {
  message: {
    type: String,
    default: 'My default value',
  },
}
```